# How can I display XML as a collapsible formatted tree in my Asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net

Ideally I want an ASP.net control with some kind of property that can be assigned to an xml string, and the control would take care of displaying the xml as an interactive treeview (reflecting the xml structure).

Comment: I don't know such control, but you can do that using an standard TreeView with few effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the standard, out-of-the-box ASP.NET TreeView?

This supports displaying any kind of hierarchical data.

Check this article, which is unrelated to XML but for displaying hierarchical data in a TreeView:

- http://aspalliance.com/732_Display_Hierarchical_Data_with_TreeView_in_ASPNET_20

Answer (score 0):

With the out of the box treeview you can either use it in conjunction with the XmlDataSource control from the tool box, something like this

```
  <form runat="server">
     <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
         <DataBindings>
             <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="name" ValueField="#InnerText" />
             <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="department" ValueField="#Value" />
         </DataBindings>
        </asp:TreeView>
     <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/XMLFile.xml">
     </asp:XmlDataSource>
    </form>
```